# VBA Runtime Error:5941 The Requested Member Of Collection Doesnot Exists

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an existing tabale in the Word Document(Macro Enabled Or .docm) i am trying to add rows to the table. But i am getting runtime errors.

```
Private Sub Method1()

Dim tbl As Table
Dim rowtbl as Row

Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
Set rowtbl = tbl.Rows.Add(BeforeRow:=tbl.Rows(1)) ---> At this line we are getting runtime error
Set coltbl = tbl.Columns.Add(BeforeColumn:=tbl.Columns(1)) ---> At this line we are getting runtime error
End Sub
```

I have followed the below steps to resolve the error.

1. ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Add BeforeRow:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(rowCnt)
2. tbl .Rows.Add BeforeRow:=tbl .Rows(rowCnt)
3. tblNew.Tables(1).Columns.Add BeforeColumn:=tblNew.Tables(1).Columns(1)
4. ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns.Add BeforeColumn:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(rowCnt)
   We are getting the same runtime error with the above mentioned word arounds.

I have followed the below reference from the MSDN.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.columns
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.rows

The References i have included for the Macro-Enabled Document is as follows.
[References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FpqC.png)

Comment: Insert this line before `Set tbl=...`  `Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Tables.Count` . What is the printed value in Immediate Window?

Comment: I have done a word around If the Word Document is saved as .docx then it is not throwing that exception. If the document is stored as MacroEnabled Document that is .docm then we are getting this error. i have added the ActiveX Object reference to the file.Do i need to add any additional references for the macro enabled document ?